# I'm trying to assign non repetitive tasks to different employees based on their shift and the number of people available for the day

Tags: excel, vba

I have already created tasks combination based on the numbers of people available for the day and per shift on my first sheet. The problem I have is that, the codes I have is that it only choses the first column from the sheet (ALL TASKS,) but what I want is that the it will choose based on the condition (number of people available for the day and the shift they are in)
[image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrgyQ.png)]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEBMQ.png]

```
here is my code for the assign tasks morning


Sub WeeklySched()

Dim TotalEmp As Integer
TotalEmp = 2
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet

'If Range("C2") = "Night" And Range("E20").Value = 3 Then
'if row C (shift) is night then fill out schedule starting from row E
Do Until ws.Cells(TotalEmp, 1) = ""
    TotalEmp = TotalEmp + 1
Loop

Dim TskSt As Worksheet
Dim TotalTask As Integer

Set TskSt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("All Tasks")
TotalTask = 2
Do Until TskSt.Cells(TotalTask, 6) = ""
    TotalTask = TotalTask + 1
Loop


WkSched = 5
'5 = row E,
Do Until ws.Cells(1, WkSched) = ""
    'Roll Back is used to check a rolling week for the task
    If WkSched < 8 Then RollBack = 2 Else RollBack = WkSched - 7




    'Check to see if there are enough employees for task
    'If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, WkSched), ws.Cells(TotalEmp - 1, WkSched))) < TotalTask - 1 Then MsgBox ("Not enough Employees for all task on " & ws.Cells(1, WkSched) & ".")
    

    DoubleTask = False
    Resch = 999999
    For AllTsk = 1 To TotalTask - 1
 
        AssignedTask = False

        For AllEmps = 2 To TotalEmp - 1
            DoneTask = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws.Range(ws.Cells(AllEmps, RollBack), ws.Cells(AllEmps, WkSched)), TskSt.Cells(AllTsk, 1))
            If DoneTask > 0 And ws.Cells(AllEmps, WkSched) = "" Then
                MaxTaskDate = WkSched
                Do Until ws.Cells(AllEmps, MaxTaskDate) = TskSt.Cells(AllTsk, 1)
                    MaxTaskDate = MaxTaskDate - 1
                 Loop
                    If MaxTaskDate = Resch Then
                        DoubleMe = True
                    Else
                        DoubleMe = False
                    End If
                    If MaxTaskDate < Resch And DoubleTask = False Then Resch = MaxTaskDate
               

            
            End If
            
            If ws.Cells(AllEmps, WkSched) = "" And (DoneTask = 0 Or (DoubleTask = True And DoubleMe = True)) Then
                ws.Cells(AllEmps, WkSched) = TskSt.Cells(AllTsk, 1)
                AssignedTask = True
                Resch = 999999
                DoubleMe = False
                Exit For
            End If
            
        Next
        
        If AssignedTask = False And DoubleTask = False Then
            DoubleTask = True
            AllTsk = AllTsk - 1
        
        End If
        If AssignedTask = True Then
            DoubleTask = False
            Resch = 9999
        End If
    Next


    WkSched = WkSched + 1
Loop
'End If
```

The problem I have is that, the codes I have is that it only choses the first column from the sheet (ALL TASKS,) but what I want is that the it will choose based on the condition (number of people available for the day and the shift they are in)

Comment: Please edit your question to provide your source data as text which can be copy/pasted. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)